# Encryption algorithm of Android Device Admin API

Tags: android, algorithm, encryption, admin, device

Does anybody know what algorithm they use when protecting an encrypted storage? I haven't found any information having read the documentation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have done some online research, and I think I found the part of the Android documentation which describes the encryption implementation of the OS.

> The actual encryption used for the filesystem for first release is 128
>   AES with CBC and ESSIV:SHA256. The master key is encrypted with 128
>   bit AES via calls to the openssl library.

Source: http://source.android.com/devices/tech/encryption/android_crypto_implementation.html

Answer (score 1):

Android security usually involves standard and commonly used cryptographic algorithms such as `AES`, `RSA`, `DSA`, and `SHA`. Additionally, higher level protocols such as `SSL` and `HTTPS` are also used to provide security to Android applications.